# Seleção de dois arquivos com Input type file

Tags: javascript, html5, node.js, react

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tenho essa seguinte situação, tenho esses dois arquivos para fazer upload com input type file.

Só que a regra é a seguinte.
Só posso apresentar para o usuário os arquivos que tem a extensão SHP

Onde ele pode selecionar é magicamente fazer a seleção do arquivo DBF,
para que ele possa fazer upload dos dois arquivos.

Sem que ele faça dois click, mas somente um.

obs:
Tenho que deixar o arquivo DBF oculto.

Tem como eu fazer isso utilizando ("React", "Javascript" e "HTML").

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Bom, javascript tem suas limitações então vc não  tem acesso ao caminho do arquivo, pois ele gera um fake path

mas vc pode fazer um workaround deixando o usuário  selecionar a pasta, ai vc faz um filtro de extensão de arquvio, ou pode optar por utilizar activeX

```
<input type="file" id="ctrl" webkitdirectory directory multiple/>
```

um exemplo  aqui https://jsfiddle.net/yfzhvbdm/